# INNER JOIN clause returning no rows while NATURAL JOIN does

Tags: sql, sqlite, inner-join, quotation-marks

I am stuck with doing a simple join in SQLite.

I have two tables - one with data, and other relational one with pointers:

- `References` contains `ReferenceID` and `Reference`
- `REL_References_Pages` contains `ReferenceID` and `PageID`

Normal join query works OK and returns good result(s):

```
SELECT Reference
FROM "References" 
NATURAL JOIN REL_References_Pages
WHERE PageID = 6
```

But if I try to do an explicit JOIN, the result is without an error, but returns no result. Where it is stuck is on the ON clause:

```
SELECT Reference
FROM "References" 
JOIN REL_References_Pages ON "REL_References_Pages.ReferenceID" = "References.ReferenceID"
WHERE PageID = 6
```

Any ideas?

I could just use NATURAL JOIN, but I am wondering why normal join doesn't work.

Also, the table `References` has a stupid name, but it is what it is.

Comment: `"REL_References_Pages.ReferenceID"` should be `"REL_References_Pages"."ReferenceID"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason you're getting empty output (no rows) is because in your on clause you are trying to compare two strings that are not equal and thus returning `false`.

Simply put, below command would yield a `false` boolean output:

```
SELECT "REL_References_Pages.ReferenceID" = "References.ReferenceID"
```

Try without quotation marks around whole `table.column` construct where it's not needed. In your case only `References` table is encapsulated originally in the data model. At least I assume that.

```
SELECT Reference
FROM "References" 
JOIN REL_References_Pages
  ON REL_References_Pages.ReferenceID = "References".ReferenceID
WHERE PageID = 6
```

Or even better with the use of aliases:

```
SELECT Reference
FROM "References" AS r 
JOIN REL_References_Pages AS rp
  ON r.ReferenceID = rp.ReferenceID
WHERE PageID = 6
```

You could also shorten the code by applying a `USING` expression instead since your column names are exactly the same in both tables and you won't need to assign aliases to tables in your query this way at all:

```
SELECT Reference
FROM "References"
JOIN REL_References_Pages USING ( ReferenceID )
WHERE PageID = 6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought that TableName.Column construct is monolithic. Putting qotes on in "References".ReferenceID fixed all.
Thanks for other two comments. I did try them before, but as selection didn't work properly, I was puzzled what's the issue.

Comment: I have added an explanation of what has actually happened when you ran your query.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I spent hours on this trying to figure it out.